# Collatz Conjecture - auto run in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make it so the python program will start with 2, do the sequence, then add 1, (so it's 3) and do it again. and to repeat until the end result isn't 1. the code I have now asks for an input, and I cant figure out how to adapt it to work

```
def collatz_seq(n):
    yield n
    while n != 1:
        n = (3 * n + 1) if (n % 2) else (n // 2)
        yield n

while True:
    try:
        start_num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        for n in collatz_seq(start_num):
            print(n, end='\n====\n')
    except ValueError:
        print('Error! Please try again.')
    if 'y' == input('Quit (y/n)? '):
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and to repeat until the end result isn't 1

Well, the Collatz Conjecture does state every number eventually reaches 1, altough it is not proven yet your program will most likely run forever because I don't see you reaching the "never before tested" numbers.

If you are fine with your program running forever, here is a small change to do it.

```
def collatz_seq(n):
    yield n
    while n != 1:
        n = (3 * n + 1) if (n % 2) else (n // 2)
        yield n

start_num = 2
while True:
    for n in collatz_seq(start_num):
        print(n, end='\n====\n')
    print("Starting new number")
    start_num+=1
```

I must add, because of the speed of the calculations this is unreadable, you might want to add a "sleep" function somewhere.

**Edit:** To clarify, if your program does find a number that NEVER reaches 1, it will run forever because it does not know whether it will reach 1 eventually or not. If every number eventually reaches 1, the program will run forever because the 'break' condition of never reaching 1 is never True. Basically, no matter what you will print numbers forever, so it is a pointless task.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the call to `collatz` outside the `while` input loop:

Maybe like this:

```
def collatz_seq(n):
    yield n
    while n != 1:
        n = (3 * n + 1) if (n % 2) else (n // 2)
        yield n

while True:
    try:
        start_num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Error! Please try again.')
        
for elt in collatz_seq(start_num):
    print(elt, end=' ')
    input()    # stops the loop until you press enter to resume
```